# Solving Quadratic Congruences in P Mod P

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Please help me solve the following:

$$2p^2 - 42p + 221 = 0 \mod p.$$

Just messing around with the numbers I noted the following:

$p = 0 \mod p$,

therefore:

$2p^2 - 42p + 221 = p \mod p$,

therefore:

$2p^2 - 43p + 221 = 0 \mod p$,

solving now:

$2p^2 - 43p + 221 = 0$,

I get:

$(2p - 17)(p - 13) = 0$.

leading to a solution of $p = 13$, and $p = 17/2$.

Are there other solutions?
How do I know and/or find them?

Comment: I realize there are infinitely many solutions to this so I will be more accurate in saying i'm interested in all integral/rational solutions. I can just arbitrarily vary the p term to produce additional solutions most of which are irrational

Comment: You tagged this as prime-numbers.  Is $p$ supposed to be prime?  If so, why on earth would you mention irrational solutions?  (Unless you really are serious about the algebraic-number-theory tag...)  And why did you jump from $\equiv 0 \mod p$ to just $=0$?

Comment: I removed the algebraic and analytic number theory tags since they do not apply.

Comment: in response to Erick Wong, I note that if there exists a solution to this congruence f(s) = 0 mod s then that solution can be rewritten as the equality f(s) = ks. setting k = 1, s = p, and f(p) = 2p^2 - 43p + 1 is one such approach, it turns out that by luck this one produced solutions. One of the answers below really explains why

Comment: btw thank you math gems for the editing! it looks much better now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ p\mid 221\!+\!pk\!\iff\! p\mid 221 = 13\cdot 17$

Comment: so is it possible to solve this problem without factoring?

Comment: As we see above, we need only factor the constant term of the polynomial, not the polynomial, since $\rm\:n\mid f(n)\iff n\mid f(0)\:$ for any polynomial $\rm\:f(x)\:$ with integer coefficients.

Comment: sorry for my inaccurate language, but that is what I meant. Must the number be factored to solve this? Or better stated, is determining the solutions to this problem equivalent to factoring the constant term?

Comment: Yes, the solutions are the prime factors of $\rm\:f(0).\:$ Computing them all is equivalent to factoring $\rm\:f(0).$

Comment: and there goes my luck... :( I thought these congruences could be solved polynomial time and therefore I could factor in polynomial time, but if it still ends up being the same problem... haha damn numbers, anyways THANKS A Ton for the help, I wasn't sure how to progress with this